# Dart: I cant instanciate a class in another class

Tags: class, dart

im trying to extend a list in Dart and use another class within this list.

Here is my example with comments where things go wrong:

```dart
import "Radio.dart"; // <= if i delete the Test class this import is unused for some reason
import "dart:collection";

class Test {
     Radio radio = new Radio(1, null, null, null); // <= works as expected
}

class RadioList<Radio> extends ListBase<Radio> {
     List<Radio> radioList = new List();

     int get length => radioList.length;

     void set length(int length) {
          radioList.length = length;
     }

     void operator []=(int index, Radio value) {
          radioList[index] = value;
     }

     Radio operator [](int index) => radioList[index];

     Radio radio = new Radio(1, null, null, null); // <= Error: The name Radio is not a class
}
```

Unfortunately i have no clue why this happens.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dart
class RadioList<Radio> extends ListBase<Radio> {
                ^^^^^
```

You are introducing a type argument named `Radio` which overshadows the `Radio` class.
Change it to

```dart
class RadioList extends ListBase<Radio> {
```

and it will work.